# Checking data type after a split operaton in sql server

Tags: sql-server, split

This is my question. I'm receiving a String with values that can be numberic or alphanumeric separated by commas:

'1,2,3,4' or '1,2,b'

My goal is to return another string with this conditions:

Numerica values : Return the same string

Alphanumeric values  : Return the values between single quotation and separated by comma  '1','2','b'

So far this is the solution that I have:

```
declare @values nvarchar(max) = '1,2,a', @result nvarchar(max)

set @result = (
    select REPLACE(@values, ',', '')
            )

begin try    
    set @result = @result*1
    set @result = @values    
end try 
begin catch
    set @result = ( select ''''+ STRING_AGG( value, ''',''') + ''''
        from string_split(@values, ','))
end catch

select @result
```

Is it possible to reach the result without involving a try/catch block? (Request of the arquitect)

Comment: `try_convert(), like, patindex()`

Comment: Your catching the entire string would still fail if it gets too long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=791749ac36d67eda7608787e3d49ced2)

```
declare @values nvarchar(max) = replicate('1,2.5,3', 15);
select case isjson('['+@values+']') when 1 then @values else ''''+replace(@values, ',', ''',''')+'''' end;
```

Comment: Incredible solution! Thanks a lot for your help @lptr

Comment: Nice solution!  Very creative.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti … there could be a problem with double quotes " " ,since isjson('[1,"2,3,4",5,6]')=1  (although the question mentions “alphanumeric separated by commas”)

Answer (score 2):

Just another option (assuming no decimals)

```
Declare @S varchar(50) = '1,2,3,4'
--Set @S ='1,2,b'

Select case when try_convert(bigint,replace(@S,',','')) is null
            then ''''+replace(@S,',',''',''')+''''
            else @S
            end
```

Results

```
'1','2','b'
```

or

```
1,2,3,4
```

**Note:**
If the value >  9,223,372,036,854,775,807 then you could use `try_convert(float,...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help John

Comment: Very compact, +1

Comment: Try it with something like `'12345,67890,54321,09876'`

Comment: @shawnt00 Clearly that would fail.  The values would have to be <= 9223372036854775807   I should have added the caveat.

Comment: @shawnt00 try_convert(float,...) would be another way to go

Comment: That's going to fail on `'1,e,2'`.

Comment: @shawnt00 My apologies for my previous comment.   We don't know the actual USE CASE.   I suspect this was just sample data, and the text would be more than just single characters.   That said, if there were an "E" it would be easy enough to trap/replace with any other character.

Answer (score 1):

You could amalgamate your logic into a single statement as follows

```
select 
  case when v like '%[A-z]%' then alpha
    else v
  end
from (select @values)v(v)
cross apply (
    select ''''+ STRING_AGG( value, ''',''') + ''''
  from string_split(v, ',')
)s(alpha)
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f1c4a6223eb3ad33f05ac11a4e18128c)

Comment: Thanks for your help Stu